# Какой Xpath написать, чтобы он не содержал tag

Tags: парсер, xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Припустим, есть такой html:

```html
<tag>
    <notag></notag>
    <href></href>
</tag>
<tag>
    <notag></notag>
    <href></href>
</tag>
<tag>
    <href></href>
</tag>
```

Мне нужно href у tag, где нет тега notag. Какой Xpath можно написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(X)HTML должен быть правильно сформирован (well-formed) и включать корневой тег.

XPath предикат `[not(notag)]` делает то, что вам нужно.

**Input (X)HTML**

```
<root>
    <tag>
        <notag></notag>
        <href>1</href>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <notag></notag>
        <href>2</href>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <href>3</href>
    </tag>
</root>
```

**XPath**

```
/root/tag[not(notag)]/href
```